# HugeInteger Class adding and subtracting taking into account negative values

Tags: java, arrays

I'm currently writing a HugeInteger class that can take in 40 digits, and I have a few comparison tests that are already written. The thing I'm having most trouble with is adding and subtraction methods. I was able to get two values to add, but don't know how to implement a negate function if one of the values are negative. My subtraction method doesn't seem to work either.

```
public void add(HugeInteger hi) {
    if (digits[NUM_DIGITS] < 0) {
    negate();
    this.subtract(hi);
  }
    int carry = 0;  
    for(int i = digits.length-1; i >=0 ;i--) {
        int cur = this.digits[i] + hi.digits[i] + carry;
        if (cur >= 10){
            cur= cur-10;
            resultAdd[i] = cur;
            carry = 1;
        } else{
            resultAdd[i] = cur;
            carry = 0;
        }
    }
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    int j=0;
    for (int i : resultAdd) {
         builder.append(i);
         this.digits[j] = i;
         j++;
    }
    this.hi = builder.toString().replace("0", "");

}

public void subtract(HugeInteger hi) {      
    for(int i = digits.length-1; i >=0 ;i--) {
        if (this.digits[i] - hi.digits[i] < 0){
            this.digits[i-1]--;
            this.digits[i]+=10;
        }
        int cur = this.digits[i] - hi.digits[i];
        this.digits[i] = cur;
    }
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    int j=0;
    for (int i : resultAdd) {
         builder.append(i);
         this.digits[j] = i;
         j++;
    }
        this.hi = builder.toString().replace("0", "");
}
    public void negate() {
    if(this.positive){
        this.positive = false;
    } else{
        this.positive = true;
        this.hi = this.hi.replace("-", "");
    }
}
```

Comment: Funny that `HugeInteger` is smaller than `BigInteger`.

Comment: Is it a homework or you just didn't know about BigInteger in Java ? There's no reason to implement something that's already there.

Comment: @MartinCuka Yes, this is for a homework assignment.